# Error 500 Yii framework PHP

Tags: php, yii

Im constantly facing this error
"Error 500 Array to string conversion". Need help guys

**JS Controller Function**

```
$scope.saveSchool=function(){
    $http.post($scope.SchoolCTRLUrl+"/saveSchool" , $scope.schoolObject)
        .success(function(responce){


        })
};
```

**Action Method**

```
public function actionsaveSchool()
{
    $school = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $schoolInfo=json_decode($school,true);
    $schoolTable=new SchoolTable();
    $schoolTable->school_name=$schoolInfo["schoolName"];
    $schoolTable->registration_code=$schoolInfo["registrationCode"];
    $schoolTable->cell_no=$schoolInfo["cellNo"];
    $schoolTable->phone_no=$schoolInfo["phoneNo"];
    $schoolTable->logo=$schoolInfo["logo"];
    $schoolTable->email_address=$schoolInfo["emailAddress"];
    $schoolTable->contact_person=$schoolInfo["contactPerson"];
    $schoolTable->address=$schoolInfo["address"];
    $schoolTable->city=$schoolInfo["city"];
    $schoolTable->district=$schoolInfo["district"];
    $schoolTable->province=$schoolInfo["province"];
    if($schoolTable->save()) {
        $id = $schoolTable->school_id;
        echo $id;
    } else{
        echo $schoolTable->getErrors();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the full stacktrace of the error. Keep in mind that questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly to the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) directives.

Comment: Sorry, but there is nothing we can say without you posting the actual implementation of that class and the content of the decoded array.

Comment: Just find where the code is trying to use an array as a string and stop doing that? The error message should include in which file and on what line it happens so it should be pretty easy for you to find.

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line :

echo $schoolTable->getErrors();
with this :

print_r($schoolTable->getErrors());